# Concatenate Python Files Together to Simplify Imports

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a directory of code filled in like this:

```
root_dir
├── root.py
├── same_step_0.py
├── same_step_1.py
├── same_step_2.py
└── utils
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── file_one.py
    └── file_two.py
```

The root.py file references the functions in the same_step files. For example:

```
# In root.py
same_step_0.generated_function()
```

The "step" files have references to functions in the 'utils' directory, with a simple import and call - e.g.

```
from utils.file_one import function_one

function_one(val="somelongstring")
```

Ok, now we get to the problem - I'm working against an API which effectively requires each "step" to be a single python file. So, what I need to do is, somehow, append all functions pulled in by each step file into a single file which I can then submit to the service.

IDEALLY, I'd love to do this with as little changes to the underlying code. So, if possible, in `same_step_0` I'd like to leave it as:

```
from utils.file_one import function_one

function_one(val="somelongstring")
```

and not have to change it to

```
# Note removing the 'utils' prefix
from file_one import function_one

function_one(val="somelongstring")
```

So, the question is, is there a way I can append all the dependent files or functions together into a single file such that it mimic'd import behavior? Or at least function call behavior? Ideas I've thought about:

- Pickling all subfiles into a serialization format and inserting at the end of the code
- Raw appending of all python files - perhaps inside an inline module?
- Scraping all files for functions and attaching them manually (however, this would not preserve namespacing)

I haven't dug into these yet - I'm curious if this is even possible

I can do a lot of generation and wrapping of code, but I'd prefer not to touch the inner code (the function_one call, for example).

Comment: It seems like you're asking for a *design* for the functionality, which is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you "can do a lot of generation and wrapping of code", what happened when you tried that? It's a little hard to give an answer here without understand why your code has this structure in the first place, nor what "containers" or "service" your using or what problems you hope for them to solve for you.

Comment: Ok, lemme try again :) The API i'm submitting the python file to APPEARS to only allow one file for execution. So, with the above it'd be 'same_step_0' or 'same_step_1'. However, the code (submitted by users) has split out functionality into other modules. I'm trying to combine everything together into a single executable file.

Comment: Made some additional clarifications in the question

Comment: You could likely do this with `types.ModuleType', `sys`, and a few tricks with exec. Let me see if I can get an example up.

Answer (score 1):

## Goal

To create a minimal set of scripts, and an interchange format that can be stored in a Python executable to recreate a module structure.

## Source

Ok here's a simple example that abuses `types.ModuleType`, `sys`, and `globals()` to do this:

```
import os
import sys
import types

class Module:
    def __init__(self, name, source=None, path=None, modules=None):
        self.name = name
        self.source = source
        self.path = path
        self.modules = modules

    def from_file(name, path):
        return Module(name, open(path).read(), path)

    def from_dir(name, path):
        return Module(name, None, path, [])

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Module(name={repr(self.name)}, source={repr(self.source)}, path={repr(self.path)}, modules={self.modules})'

    def to_dict(self):
        data = { 'name': self.name }
        if self.source is not None:
            data['source'] = self.source
        if self.path is not None:
            data['path'] = self.path
        if self.modules is not None:
            data['modules'] = [i.to_dict() for i in self.modules]
        return data

    @staticmethod
    def from_dict(data):
        modules = None
        if 'modules' in data:
            modules = [Module.from_dict(i) for i in data.pop('modules')]
        return Module(**data, modules=modules)

def get_modname(parent, module):
    if parent is None:
        return module
    if module == '__init__':
        return parent
    return f'{parent}.{module}'

def compile_module(module, parent=None):
    modname = get_modname(parent, module.name)
    mod = types.ModuleType(modname)
    exec(module.source, mod.__dict__)
    path = os.path.realpath(module.path)
    mod.__path__ = os.path.dirname(path)
    mod.__file__ = path
    sys.modules[modname] = mod
    globals()[modname] = mod
    return mod

def compile_module_recursive(package, parent=None):
    # Need to do this recursively.
    mod = compile_module(package, parent)
    if not package.modules:
        return mod
    for submodule in package.modules:
        submod = compile_module_recursive(submodule, parent=get_modname(parent, package.name))
        if not hasattr(mod, submodule.name):
            setattr(mod, submodule.name, submod)
    return mod

def read_module_recursive(directory, parent=None):
    # The module order is first the:
    #   1. All submodules
    #   2. Then definitions inside
    # Then, need to define `__name__`, `__path__` and `__file__`.
    cwd = os.getcwd()
    realpath = os.path.realpath(directory)
    parent_dir = os.path.dirname(realpath)
    base_dir = os.path.basename(realpath)
    if parent is None:
        parent = Module.from_dir(base_dir, realpath)

    os.chdir(realpath)
    for entry in os.listdir(realpath):
        path = os.path.join(realpath, entry)
        if os.path.isfile(path):
            name, ext = os.path.splitext(entry)
            if not ext == '.py':
                continue
            if name == '__init__':
                parent.path = path
                parent.source = open(path).read()
            else:
                parent.modules.append(Module.from_file(name, path))
        elif os.path.isdir(path):
            if entry == '__pycache__':
                continue
            path = os.path.join(realpath, entry)
            # Must have processed __init__.py
            if not os.path.isfile(f'{path}/__init__.py'):
                continue
            module = Module.from_dir(entry, path)
            parent.modules.append(module)
            read_module_recursive(entry, module)

    os.chdir(cwd)
    return parent


# SAMPLE USE
# ----------
#   module = read_module_recursive('mylib')
#   data = module.to_dict()  # can store as a Python dict.
#   module = Module.from_dict(data)
#   compile_module_recursive(module)
```

## How it works

Basically, it reads all `.py` files from all modules, recursively. It currently does not support extension types, only pure Python files. It then creates an intermediate, tree-like type for the entire module tree. It provides easy serialization to and from dict, so it's much easier to copy-and-paste it into your executable file.

## Example use

Say I have the following directory structure:

```
mylib/
    __init__.py
    a.py
    b.py
    c/
        __init__.py
        d.py
```

It properly respects the import order, and how it variable assignments override imports or submodules. Please note that it imports everything recursively all at once, which differs than the traditional import structure.

**mylib/**init**.py**

```
a = 'e'
```

**mylib/a.py**

```
def afunc(a):
    return str(a)

class AClass:
    def x(self):
        return 1
```

**mylib/b.py**

```
def bfunc(b):
    return repr(b)

class BClass:
    def x(self):
        return 1
```

**mylib/c/**init**.py**

**mylib/c/d.py**

```
def dfunc(d):
    return str(d)

class DClass:
    def x(self):
        return 1
```

**Example**

```
>>> module = read_module_recursive('mylib')
>>> data = module.to_dict()  # can store as a Python dict.
>>> module = Module.from_dict(data)
>>> compile_module_recursive(module)
>>> mylib
<module 'mylib' from 'C:\\Users\\user\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\lib\\mylib\\__init__.py'>
>>> mylib.a
'e'
>>> from mylib.a import afunc # still works
>>> afunc(54)
'54'
>>> import mylib # works because `'mylib'` is in `sys.modules`.
```

Congrats: this is a hack, but it works, and it works nicely, and it uses Python's own packaging system to do everything, so it's much more resilient than copying and pasting. After compiling, it also respects imports (due to adding them to sys.modules). It also respects `__doc__`, and other attributes.

## License

Public Domain or Unlicensed. Use as you see fit. Attribution would be nice, but not required.

Comment: HOLY COW - this is absolutely amazing and exactly what i'm looking for. THANK YOU